# List<MyUrl> из List<Uri> - как быстро убрать не дубли по условию с использованием linq?

Tags: c#, list, linq, uri

Есть `List<MyUrl> lists`

```
    List<MyUrl> lists = new List<MyUrl>
    {
        new MyUrl()
        {
            urls = new List<Uri>() 
            { 
                new Uri("https://1.com"), new Uri("https://2.com"), new Uri("https://3.com"), new Uri("https://4.com") 
            }
        },
        new MyUrl()
        {
            urls = new List<Uri>()
            {
                new Uri("https://7.com"), new Uri("https://2.com"), new Uri("https://3.com"), new Uri("https://4.com")
            }
        },
        new MyUrl()
        {
            urls = new List<Uri>()
            {
                new Uri("https://8.com"), new Uri("https://02.com"), new Uri("https://3.com"), new Uri("https://4.com")
            }
        },
        new MyUrl()
        {
            urls = new List<Uri>()
            {
                new Uri("https://9.com"), new Uri("https://2.com"), new Uri("https://3.com"), new Uri("https://4.com")
            }
        }
    };
```

В MyUrl содержатся `List<Uri> urls`

```
class MyUrl
{
    public List<Uri> urls { get; set; }
}
```

Как в lists оставить только те MyUrl, которые между собой имеют минимум 3 общих элемента?

То есть в этом примере лишний это

```
    new MyUrl()
    {
        urls = new List<Uri>()
        {
            new Uri("https://8.com"), new Uri("https://02.com"), new Uri("https://3.com"), new Uri("https://4.com")
        }
    }
```

Так как у всех остальных имеется единый набор из минимум 3-х элементов:

```
https://2.com
https://3.com
https://4.com
```

Дополнение:

Спасибо за предложенное решение, но оно некорректно срабатывает, к примеру, на следующих данных:

```
            List<MyUrl> lists = new List<MyUrl>
        {
            new MyUrl()
            {
                urls = new List<Uri>() 
                { 
                    new Uri("https://1.com"), new Uri("https://2.com"), new Uri("https://3.com"), new Uri("https://4.com"), new Uri("https://5.com"),
                }
            },
            new MyUrl()
            {
                urls = new List<Uri>()
                {
                    new Uri("https://01.com"), new Uri("https://02.com"), new Uri("https://03.com"), new Uri("https://2.com"),
                    new Uri("https://3.com"), new Uri("https://4.com"), new Uri("https://5.com")
                }
            },
            new MyUrl()
            {
                urls = new List<Uri>()
                {
                    new Uri("https://1.com"), new Uri("https://2.com"), new Uri("https://3.com"), new Uri("https://333.com"), new Uri("https://444.com")
                }
            },
            new MyUrl()
            {
                urls = new List<Uri>()
                {
                    new Uri("https://1.com"), new Uri("https://2.com"), new Uri("https://3.com"), new Uri("https://6666.com"), new Uri("https://7777.com")
                }
            }
        };
```

Тут лишний:

```
            new MyUrl()
            {
                urls = new List<Uri>()
                {
                    new Uri("https://01.com"), new Uri("https://02.com"), new Uri("https://03.com"), new Uri("https://2.com"),
                    new Uri("https://3.com"), new Uri("https://4.com"), new Uri("https://5.com")
                }
            }
```

Так как у всех остальных имеется единый набор из минимум 3-х элементов:

```
https://1.com
https://2.com
https://3.com
```

Как можно сделать более корректно?

Comment: Что именно у вас не получается? Покажите пожалуйста вашу попытку решить задачу.

Comment: Я не могу получить результат, так как не понимаю как мне найти элементы у которых нет минимум 3-х общих url со всеми остальными, то есть сравнивать все со всеми и получать результат, как описаны в примере у меня никак не получилось

Comment: Во втором примере, в "лишнем" списке присутствуют **те же самые** элементы: `new Uri("https://2.com"), new Uri("https://3.com"), new Uri("https://4.com")` - поэтому непонятно - почему он считается лишним?

Comment: так как у других нет Uri("https://2.com"), new Uri("https://3.com"), new Uri("https://4.com") то есть на выходе получится группа, внутри которой КАЖДЫЙ (в этом вся суть) элемент содержит одинаковый для всех набор урлов. То есть сравнение идет не с соседними или первым, а все со всеми - вот тут я и не понимаю, как сделать чтобы все работало.

Comment: Ответ был удален, потому что он, как оказалось, не отвечает на вопрос автора. Я не имею понятия, как решать эту задачу. `Я не могу получить результат, так как не понимаю как мне найти элементы у которых нет минимум 3-х общих url со всеми остальными` - это условие не соответствует действительности.